# How to hide Columns on a layout screen size on react-bootstrap?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I want to hide `<Col></Col>` on small screen devices. I checked out react-bootstrap documentation, but it does not mention a way to do that.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/

In plain `react + bootstrap` that can be achieved `<div className="hidden-xs"></div>`, but using the library react-bootstrap that no longer works. I tried: `<Col xs="0"></Col>` and similar but that did not work.

Does anyone know how to hide a react-bootstrap Column?

Answer (score 16):

I suppose you are using the latest `react-bootstrap` lib, which is using the `bootstrap` v4.
If you want to hide something by default and then want to display on a selected media size you should use the `display` utility classnames.

For example, if you want to hide a `Col` on `small` screen size but want to show on `large` screen:

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col sm={12} lg={4} className="d-none d-lg-block">
      {/* your content */}
    </Col>
    <Col sm={12} lg={8}>
      {/* your content */}
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

If you are using the `display` utils, the order of classnames are important.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve the same effect in `react-bootstrap` using the class `d-*-none`. For example, only displaying  a `Col` when the screen is medium or larger:

```js
<Row>
   <Col className='d-md-block d-sm-none'>
      ...
   </Col
   ...
</Row>
```